# sales_flat_order_payment and column: method = null last 2 orders

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, ce-1.9.2.2

Hoping a seasoned Magento guy can help out here.

So for any new orders all of a sudden the table: `sales_flat_order_payment` and column: `method` is not being updated for ONLY the last 2 orders. It was working perfectly fine and then over the weekend something has gone a miss. We are using v1.9.2.2 with no changes having been done over. It was working perfectly fine with a custom file which we use to call the following:

```
("SELECT `method` FROM `sales_flat_order` LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order_payment` ON `sales_flat_order`.`entity_id` = `sales_flat_order_payment`.`entity_id` WHERE `sales_flat_order`.`increment_id` = '" . $row['increment_id'] . "'");
```

Was working fine. Values were pulled in to our custom script with no isses. I can also manually go to phpmyadmin view: `sales_flat_order_payment` and column: `method` which does have the payment method used inserted. HOWEVER on doing a query:

```
SELECT  `method` , increment_id, remote_ip, updated_at, customer_email
FROM  `sales_flat_order` 
LEFT JOIN  `sales_flat_order_payment` ON  `sales_flat_order`.`entity_id` =  `sales_flat_order_payment`.`entity_id` 
WHERE sales_flat_order.updated_at >  '2016-02-23'
ORDER BY updated_at DESC
```

returns the last 2 orders on that sales_flat_order_payment and column: method as being NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is right here in the query:

```
 `sales_flat_order`.`entity_id` =  `sales_flat_order_payment`.`entity_id`
```

`order.entity_id` is not the same as `order_payment.entity_id`. They may have matched up in the past, but there is no guarantee that will always be the case. They are separate identifiers. You should link the tables on `order_payment.parent_id` instead, like so:

```
 `sales_flat_order`.`entity_id` =  `sales_flat_order_payment`.`parent_id`
```

Your query is returning `NULL` for some columns because it is not finding any record in `sales_flat_order_payment` to join at all.

Comment: so i should be using this instead: "SELECT `method` FROM `sales_flat_order` LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order_payment` ON `sales_flat_order`.`entity_id` = `sales_flat_order_payment`.`parent_id` WHERE `sales_flat_order`.`increment_id` = '" . $row['increment_id'] . "'");

Comment: You shouldn't be using direct queries at all, use Magento's models and collections... but yes, that should fix your problem. Better way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26349245/2336164 giving you `$order` and `$order->getPayment()`. `method` would be `$order->getPayment()->getMethod()`.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, yup seems to have fixed it. Its already an existing code that I'm having to work with that pushes data externally so having to live with it for the moment until it can be scrapped. What confused me was that its been working very well for quite a while and then all of a sudden its stopped working. Do you perhaps know if a sql upgrade on the server to a newer version would stop it from working? or is it normal that the column method called by the query in my post above would show the first 2 orders listed there with NULL values? and thus was just when not if it would fail!

Comment: Most likely some order failed during processing, in such a way that it reserved an entity_id from the order table but not from the order_payment table. If you look at sales_flat_order, you'll probably find a spot where a couple entity_ids get skipped.

Comment: yup, i can see quite a few entity_ids missing! most likely cause when the server fell over on the weekend ;( thanks for your input Ryan. FAST and EFFICIENT answer to something i was looking to hard at. fresh pair of eyes always helps :)